# Invoking a local notification with UNUserNotificationCenter right now

Tags: ios, swift

How can I invoke a local notification right now? Instead of setting a time interval in the future? This code will show a notification 5 seconds in the future. I want it to be invoked now.

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false)

let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        //error
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you set timeInterval to nil?

Answer (score 0):

Because timeInterval must be greater than 0, you can try put 0.1 in timeInterval.

Or you can fire local notification at specific time.(now time)

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.timeZone], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
```

Comment: oh okay. 0.1 works but I was wondering if maybe there is a righter way to do that. But I guess not.